# How to listen to audio with HDMI on the TV on Linux

Tags: audio, linux-mint, hdmi

I am using Linux Mint 15 "Cinnamon". I've got some videos that I want to play on the TV. I connected my laptop to the TV using HDMI. the video can be seen, but the audio is playing on my computer. When I tried Windows, the audio was playing on the TV. I bought the HDMI cable because the speakers on my laptop are weak. Please help me listen to audio on the TV. I use Linux because my Windows browser is slow. In `output device`, I don't get the HDMI output option.

Answer (score 6):

In the toolbar speaker icon, if you click it, do you get "Output device..." as an option? That should let you select the HDMI output.

Pasted years later and by someone else, on Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon in German: Klang = Sound, Ausgang = Output, then click on HDMI:

[image]

If not, you can try running `alsamixer` to make sure that the audio for the HDMI output is active (press F6 to select different devices). If activating it doesn't work (or if it's already active), you could maybe install `pavucontrol` and use that to select the output device. This works in distros like Xubuntu, not sure how it goes in Mint.